# What is the importance of central limit theorem in physics?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, statistics

I have come across [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) in statistical mechanics texts. But I'm not being able to fathom its importance. Can someone explain with an example that appeal to a physics student?

Comment: thermal noise in a resistor/amplifier/radio/tv ...

Comment: Renormalized actions on the lattice.

Comment: This seems to be an open-ended list question with no identifiable correct answer, which are usually viewed as *too broad*.

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples you could give, I guess. I would like to contribute with a very simple one that you may find interesting: **diffusion**.

Consider a particle sitting at $x=0$ at time $t=0$. We work in discrete time and space. At every timestep $\delta t, 2\delta t,$ etc, the new position of the particle is given by:

$$ x_{t+\delta t} = x_t + S\delta x$$

where $S$ is a random variable which is +1 with probability 1/2 and -1 with probability 1/2. Clearly, after $n$ timesteps, starting at 0

$$x_{n\delta t} = (S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_n)\delta x$$

the $S_i$ are independent, identically distributed and have finite variance. Therefore the quantity in brackets tends to a Gaussian when $n$ is large. If we go to the continuum limit by having $\delta t \to 0$ and $\delta x \to 0$, the probability of our particle being at location $x$ at time $t$ is Gaussian, with variance increasing with time, whence the diffusion.

Note that this result can also be found using the diffusion partial differential equation, which is a completely different way and may be interesting for teaching purposes.

Apologies for not providing all mathematical details.

Comment: Is this a random walk?

Comment: Yes it is. On a 1d lattice.